# Copy a Google Spreadsheet from one Google Drive to another

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

We're selling a Google Spreadsheet.  After the customer purchases it, we need to copy the file to their account.  Having a hell of a time figuring out which API's to use and how it would work.

Comment: I'm looking desperately for this issue. What's the news ? =/.

Comment: Did you find anyhting?

Comment: Never found a solution =/

Comment: No solution at this point? I'm having this problem

Answer (score 0):

Patch the existing file with its new folder:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<fileId>
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>

{ "parents": [{ "id": "<new folder's id>" }] }
```

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

Comment: 1) the file is on a different account so this would cause auth issues
2) we need to copy it, not move it

Answer (score 0):

Files: [copy](http://ttps://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy)
Requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#auth)

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/copy
```

Change Path parameters `fileId` string  The ID of the file to copy. [*Try it here*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it)